# iOS addGestureRecognizer with cancelsTouchesInView = false does not work with subview buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have ViewController with UIGestureRecognizer implemented this way:

```
// Extension for GestureRecognizer
extension UIViewController {
    func addGestureRecognizer() {
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.endEditing(false)
    }
}
```

As you can see, cancelsTouchesInView is set to false by default. It works fine with main view with searchBar and textFields. Keyboard is being dismissed and touches are translated to view's objects - buttons and so on.

But I have added subview that works like AlertView with several UITextFields and UIButtons. And here is a problem. When subview is presented and I'm tapping on any button of this subview - gestureRecognizer reacts and keyboard disappears. But nothing else happens. So I have to tap the second time on the button to make it pressed.
[image]

I have tried to change target of UITapGestureRecognizer from self to self.mySubViewName, like this:

```
    func addGestureRecognizer() {
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.addingItemView, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.endEditing(false)
    }
```

This way GestureRecognizer started to work with subview buttons properly, but is not able to work with main view. I started getting "Unrecognized selector was sent" error when trying to dismiss keyboard for searchbar for example. I have tried to implement separate function addGestureRecognizerForSubView, but still getting "Unrecognized selector was sent..." error.

Also tried to add this:

```
extension MenuTableViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return touch.view == self.addingItemView
    }
}
```

but nothing changes.

I've checked a lot of answers here, but was not able to find my case. Can anybody advise? I can share my ViewController class, but it's too heavy and looks ugly with programmatically added subview :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a subview behind the alert and add the gesture to it not to `self.view`

```
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.otherView, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.otherView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

Edit: your suggest to add it to a subview is right

```
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.addingItemView, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

But you still add the gesture to self.view here

```
      self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

change to

```
      self.addingItemView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

Comment: Hey! It looks like correct answer, but it does not work when I implement both methods - self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap) and self.addingItemView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap) for main view and subview, the second one does not work. And shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer does not help here :(

Comment: My main view has searchBar and I want to use GestureReognizer to hide keyboard. And I want another GestureRecognizer to hide keyboard for the subview.

Comment: when the alert is presented disable the mainview's gesture and re - enable after you close the alert

Comment: agrhh... will keep fighting. Cannot understand what is happing with these recognizers and selectors.

Comment: I had same problem with UITableView, tableView.delaysContentTouches = false solved the issue